# compose.material3 duplicate classes when building release

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm getting this error when I try to build a release version of my app (debug builds fine):

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type androidx.compose.material3.ScrollableTabData is defined multiple times: C:\\Users\\user\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\5ff01f70226ed9387e9f0b0d3b8f6ded\\transformed\\jetified-material3-1.1.2-runtime.jar:androidx/compose/material3/ScrollableTabData.class, C:\\Users\\user\\studioprojects\\project\\androidApp\\build\\intermediates\\asm_instrumented_project_classes\\release\\androidx\\compose\\material3\\ScrollableTabData.class","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\5ff01f70226ed9387e9f0b0d3b8f6ded\\transformed\\jetified-material3-1.1.2-runtime.jar"}],"tool":"R8"}
```

Sometimes it's a different class (e.g. TabSlot), but always related to Material3 tabs.

I've tried using several versions of Material3, but nothing makes a difference.

I've tried `isMinifyEnabled = false` in my build.gradle. This causes a different, but essentially the same error (looks like the error just gets hit at a later point if minification is off)

I've tried the following in my proguard rules (individually, together and various combinations):

```
-keep class androidx.compose.material3.** { *; }
-dontobfuscate
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
```

I've tried various different Android Studio Versions, AGP versions, Kotlin versions but I just hit the same error every time.

At this point I feel like I've read the entirety of Stack Overflow, most of the rest of the (Android) internet, and have no ideas where to turn next.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually figured this out. I'd duplicated the Material3 Scrollable Tab class and made some changes (to allow for centering), and it was this duplicate class that was causing the issue